# Symfony3 LDAP authentication bind credentials

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, symfony

I'm struggling with the ldap authentication within a symfony project.

My service looks like this:

```
ldap:
    class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
    factory: ['Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap', 'create']
    arguments:
        - 'ext_ldap'
        - host: 'ldap.example.com'
```

The bind and a example query to the ldap server are working fine:

```
$ldap = $this->get('ldap');
$ldap->bind('binduser', 'bindpw');
$query = $ldap->query('OU=MyBusiness,DC=example,DC=com', 'sAMAccountName=xxx');
```

Now I want to authenticate against the ldap server. I have used the firewall settings from http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html#configuration-example-for-form-login.
But the great question is where to put the bind credentials here?

The corresponding log entry here is:

```
php.DEBUG: Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials
```

So it's pretty obvious what's missing, but I couldn't find a way to provide the bind credentials to form_login_ldap.

The reference on http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html also doesn't show how to provide them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The bind credentials are those submitted from the user in the form.

As you see here http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html#configuration-example-for-form-login

```
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'uid={username},dc=example,dc=com'
```

you just need to specify the dn_string and the user will be authenticated with his credentials calling a ldap_bind.

Is your user (the one you entered in the form) authorized to ldap_bind?
The one you enter in the config of the LDAP user provider, if you have one, is useless for this purpose.

The form login is a traditional login form that can be done following this http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: Hi, no the users which will enter their credentials within the login form are not allowed to bind to the ldap server.
There is one specific user which is allowed to connect to the ldap server and with this user I could execute the queries.

The basic requirement for this project is that there are two user directories. (At least I guess I have to solve it with two user directories)

Comment: then you can't use `form_login_ldap`. you should implement your own system. take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_password_authenticator.html

Comment: Okay - yes the more I read and test, the more I'm realizing that I have to write my own authenticator.
Thanks for your support ;)